# How to get the via url (or site name) on a wordpress network's home page?

Tags: multisite

Hy everyone!
I listed the all network posts on my multisite to my network-home's homepage with "WDS Multisite Aggregate" plugin. This works fine, but now I want to get the author/publisher subsite's domains above each posts, similar to: by Author_name, just in this case so: via subsite_url.

So now, if Author1 publishing on his own site, example [subsite1.network.com] a new post, this post immediately appears on the homepage of [network.com], and appear above of the post content the Author's username, thus: by Author1.

Besides this, the all "shared" post's link-title control to the publisher site, so example, when on the homepage of [network.com] a new post appears, this post title shows to [subsite.network.com/current-post-idx] when I use this `the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title" style="" itemprop="headline"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );` and if I open [network.com/current-post-idx], this redirect to [subsite.network.com/current-post-idx].

So, `get_permalink()` shows to the original post where the author publishing that.

Now I would like that similar to this appear above of the post content the Author's site, where can he publishing the current post, thus: via [subsite1.network.com].

So, if `get_permalink()` = [subsite1.network.com/current-post-idx], in this same case how can I get simply [subsite1.network.com]?

... `get_home_url()` and `get_site_url()` obviously shows to [network.com] because that particular homepage it belongs this.

Sorry, this is my first question here, ago this I find everything on the subject on the internet, but about this I did't find anything anywhere.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/290641/edit) to show us the code you're using to make `subsite1`'s posts appear on `network.com`?

Comment: I use the "Multisite Aggregate" plugin to this, and on the homepage of [network.com] I list the posts with "Ajax Load More" plugin with this shortcode `[ajax_load_more container_type="div" post_type="post" posts_per_page="30" transition_container="false" images_loaded="true" button_label="Older Tumbs" button_loading_label="Loading Tumbs ..." transition="masonry" masonry_selector=".inside-article2" category__not_in="37"]`.

Comment: Ah, I somehow managed to miss the plugin note (even though it's right at the start of your question). Have you checked with the Multisite Aggregate plugin support streams? They might have an answer for you.

Comment: Not yet, but my first thought was, this can be solved elsewhere, because on [network.com] the all "shared" post's link-title control to the publisher site, so example, when on the homepage of [network.com] a new post appears, this post title shows to [subsite.network.com/current-post-idx] when I use this `the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title" style="" itemprop="headline"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );` and if I open [network.com/current-post-idx], this redirect to [subsite.network.com/current-post-idx].

Comment: So get_permalink() shows to the original post where the author publishing that.

Comment: Sorry, the plugin full name is "WDS Multisite Aggregate". I improved this in my question.

Comment: Answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292780/how-to-get-blog-id-from-permalink/292785#292785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The ultimate answer here, if you have a subdomain based multisite**

(This works in every case with subdomain based multisite, if your canonical URLs are okay -> so your permalinks shows to the parent posts...).

Only replace the `yournetworkdomain.com` to your network domain:

```
$posturl = esc_url( get_permalink() );
$find = array( 'http://', 'https://' );
$replace = '';
$purepostaddress = str_replace( $find, $replace, $posturl );
$afterdomain = explode('yournetworkdomain.com', $purepostaddress);
$currentpostslug = $afterdomain[1];
$find = array( '' . $currentpostslug . '' );
$replace = '';
$parentblogaddress = str_replace( $find, $replace, $purepostaddress );

$blogid = get_blog_id_from_url('' . $parentblogaddress . '');
$blog_details = get_blog_details($blogid);
```

And so get the parent blog's link:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_home_url( $blogid ) . '" 
target="_blank">'.$blog_details->blogname.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `get_site_url()`, use [`get_home_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/). This will return the URL of the site you're in.

You can also get the URL of a different site in your Multisite network by passing that site's `blog_id` (ie, `$url = get_home_url( 2 );`).

(I suspect that `get_site_url()` is a holdover from the early days of Multisite; when Multisite was originally moved into WordPress, you created a **site** of **blogs**. The terminology has evolved, so that we now think of a **network** of **sites**, but some of the functions still reflect the old terms.)

Comment: Hy Pat, thanks for your fast reply! The problem is, the plugin dynamically fills to the main site's home every new post in the network, so the blog_id (in `$url = get_home_url( 2 );`) need it has to change dynamically, based on, where did the plugin fill it the post, so what sites on publishing the current post.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/290641/edit) and add in some more code, for some context, it might be easier to help you solve your problem. Show us what you've got so far, and explain fully what you're trying to accomplish.