# How to get blog id from permalink?

Tags: permalinks, multisite, blog-id

I need to get blog ids (or site ids) on my multisite, from permalinks.

THIS PROBLEM IS NOT A PLUGIN SPECIFIC, but here the full story:
I listed the all network posts on my multisite to my network-home's homepage with "WDS Multisite Aggregate" plugin. This works fine, and the "aggregated" post's permalink's shows to the parent post's.
(thus clarifying: The child posts will link back to the parent post.)

So, I have posts on my network's home with permalinks to the subsite's posts.

I want to get from these links the publisher subsite's id, because if I know these site's ids, I can get the publisher site's homeurl, like this:

`$myblogid = [MISSING CODE, wherewith I get blog id from permalink]
$mysuburl = get_home_url( $myblogid );`

If I use the `get_current_blog_id()`, these getting the network's home id.

I know that, possible get blog id from url thus:

`$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("example.com", "/blog1/");`
or
`$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("blog1.example.com");`

but this not working with post's permalinks, just only with blog urls.

very simplified:
I have a permalink what this: subsite.network.com/post-url
Now I want getting this: subsite.network.com

Comment: on which page do you need this home URL ? on the list of posts created by WDS Multisite Aggregate ?

Comment: yes, this plugin cloned the all posts from the network to the network home site... But these cloned post's permalinks shows to the parent's post.

Comment: (and the plugin automatically redirect the child posts to the parent posts, but this dont relevant.)

Comment: I want to use more than one page, that's why I thought this get_blogid's from permalink approach.

Comment: then on this list (your first comment) you want to replace post link like `subsite.network.com/post-url` with the link `subsite.network.com` ?

Comment: No, I want to add a via url to the posts, like this:
post content </br>
permalink </br>
via: sitelink </br>
tags: tag1, tag2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the plugin "WDS Multisite Aggregate" store the blog identifier in a meta of the cloned post.
then in the template file wich display the cloned posts, you can retrieve the home url of the original website with that :

```
$blogid = $GLOBALS["post"]->blogid;
$blog_details = get_blog_details($blogid);
// the home URL is in $blog_details->home
```

I hope this is what you need because calculating the original post identifier from the permalink consumes considerably more ressources.

Comment: Thank you, this perfect!
If you link this to here, I accept for answer there too: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290641/how-to-get-the-via-url-or-site-name-on-a-wordpress-networks-home-page